# Spring MVC and jQuery GET

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring

I'm trying to get a list of items from `/keyword` and append the ID to the `#test`, but for some reason the error alert always gets triggered. I'm learning ajax, so maybe there is a syntax error in the call and I can't see it. Also, should I put the function inside `$(document).ready(..)` or outside it?

ajax:

```
function keyword(){
    var keyword = $("#item-name-form-keyword").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "k=" + keyword,
        url: "http://localhost:8080/keyword",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(id){
                $("#test").append(id);
            });

        },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

Form:

```
<div class="item-name-container">
  <form id="item-name-form" method="GET">
    <input id="item-name-form-keyword" type="text" placeholder="Item name..">
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/keyword",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,  
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<Items> getByKeyword(@RequestParam("k") String keyword){

    List<Items> items = itemService.findByKeyword(keyword);


    return items;

}
```

Query

```
@Query("from Item as r where r.itemName like concat('%', :keyword, '%')")
Iterable<Item> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

Comment: do you have any server side error ?

Comment: No, no errors. The controller also works if I do ``/keyword?k=some_key``

Comment: You should use **"k=" + keyword** instead of **"k=" + key**

Comment: yeah I've changed that a few minutes ago - still

Comment: could you please add **xhr,status,error** as parameter in your error function and try to print in console. ? like error: function(xhr,status,error){ console.log(xhr); console.log(status); console.log(error)

Comment: which one do you want me to post? there are many - ``abort``, ``always``, ``catch``, ``fail``.. etc

Comment: Instead of **error: function(){alert("ERROR");}** try **error: function(xhr,status,error){ 
   console.log(xhr); 
   console.log(status); 
   console.log(error);
  }** and see what each log print. in console of your browser